# Positional argument error even though no obvious issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825350/mismatched-positional-arguments-error-even-though-no-mismatch) about my issue, and even though I edited the question to include a full example, the question was not re-opened, so I'm posting it as a new question.

I have a clickable label that is supposed to pass parameters when clicked. However, when I click the label, I get:

```
TypeError: configure_towns() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Obviously this means that somewhere a call to configure_towns is being made that's receiving an unexpected parameter, but nowhere in my code does this occur. I have another button that utilizes a factory function to pass parameters to the function, and that works without any issue.

Here's a full application you can copy and paste into a Python editor to show my issue. You will notice that clicking the button works just fine, while clicking the label returns the stated error, even though `configure_towns()` is successfully called earlier in order to display the labels in the first place.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])

main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

class MainWindow(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle('Title')
        self.setGeometry(1200, 200, 350, 500)

        # Preparing the button
        first_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        first_layout.addWidget(QWidget())
        self.note_factory(first_layout, -1)()
        main_layout.addLayout(first_layout)

        # Preparing the label
        self.place_list = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']

        second_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        second_layout.addWidget(QWidget())
        self.town_factory(self.place_list, second_layout, None)()
        main_layout.addLayout(second_layout)

    def note_factory(self, layout, count):
        ## Every time you click the button, the counter increases
        count += 1
        def configure_notes():
            temp = layout.itemAt(0).widget()
            temp.deleteLater()

            temp = QWidget()
            temp.layout = QVBoxLayout()
            temp.setLayout(temp.layout)

            label = QLabel(str(count) + ' clicks')
            temp.layout.addWidget(label)

            button = QPushButton('Click')
            temp.layout.addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(self.note_factory(layout, count))

            layout.addWidget(temp)

        return configure_notes

    def town_factory(self, place_list, layout, label):
        ## Every time you click "Click Me!" The appropriate label appears.
        def configure_towns():
            temp = layout.itemAt(0).widget()
            temp.deleteLater()

            temp = QWidget()
            temp.layout = QVBoxLayout()
            temp.setLayout(temp.layout)

            if label != None:
                lab = QLabel(label + ' clicked')
                temp.layout.addWidget(lab)

            for place in place_list:                
                p_grp = QHBoxLayout()  

                open_lab = QLabel('Click Me!')
                open_lab.mouseReleaseEvent = self.town_factory(place_list, layout, place)

                p_grp.addWidget(open_lab)

                p_grp.addWidget(QLabel(place))
                p_grp.addStretch(1)

                temp.layout.addLayout(p_grp)

            layout.addWidget(temp)
        return configure_towns

window = MainWindow()

window.setLayout(main_layout)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You have just edited it 11 hours ago so many probably have not seen it (there are fewer users on the weekend than on weekdays) so I recommend waiting instead of posting the same question several times.

Comment: Cool. I'll come back in a few weeks and hopefully 4 other moderators feel generous enough to reopen my question. 

Just kinda frustrating since my original question contains all the relevant information to my problem, but apparently that's not enough for StackOverflow

Comment: 1) I did not have enough information since it could not be reproduced, so vote to close it, 2) Currently only 3 user votes are required with the privilege of reopening questions (I have changed the threshold of votes for months to reopen a question) and you already have 2 votes so your question will probably reopen in a few hours. 3) With the above I recommend that you take the time to write a quality question: That clearly explain what you want and provide a [mre]